# Jquery autocomplete from XML (multiple values)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of airports in XML format which I would like to use with jquery autocomplete.

The XML file looks like this:

```
<item code="AAR" airport="Aarhus" country="Denmark" />
```

When a selection is made, in addition to filling the search input box with "Aarhus" I want to alert the contents of "code".

I have tried like so:

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "airports.xml",
      dataType: "xml",
      success: function( xmlResponse ) {
        var data = $("item", xmlResponse ).map(function() {
          return {
            value: $( "airport", this ).text(),
            code: $( "code", this ).text()
          };
        }).get();
        $( "#airport_from" ).autocomplete({
          source: data,
          minLength: 0,
          select: function( event, ui ) {
             alert(ui.item.code);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

The alert however just shows "undefined", what am I missing?

Comment: You sure your mapped `data` is in correct format?

Comment: Can you post your `data` which you are passing to `autocomplete`?

Comment: The code is based on the example from the jquery-ui page, the content of the .xml they are using there is in a different format `<geoname>
<name>London</name>
<geonameId>2643743</geonameId>
</geoname>` Where in the example `data` is `geoname` and they get the values for `name` and `geonameId` So I guess the problem is the format of my .xml? What would I need to adjust in that case?

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue may be that when you give autocomplete a list of objects it expects label and value properties.

http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

Maybe try this:

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "airports.xml",
      dataType: "xml",
      success: function( xmlResponse ) {
        var data = $("item", xmlResponse ).map(function() {
          return {
            label: $( "airport", this ).text(),
            value: $( "code", this ).text()
          };
        }).get();
        $( "#airport_from" ).autocomplete({
          source: data,
          minLength: 0,
          select: function( event, ui ) {
             alert(ui.item.value);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up converting the XML to CSV and back to XML which has changed the format to:

```
 <airport>
 <airport_code>AAR</airport_code>
 <airport_name>Aarhus</airport_name>
 <airport_country>Denmark</airport_country>
 </airport>
```

And the code is now working as expected.